# Does binary black holes evaporate slower because they compete for attracting virtual particles?

Tags: black-holes, hawking-radiation

Is it true that if 2 black holes are near each other, such as binary black holes, will evaporate slower than when they are far apart, because they are competing for attracting virtual particles each other?

Comment: If black holes could actually accrete virtual particles, their mass should grow continuously without the presence of any real matter.

Comment: Please note that evaporating black holes are not emitting virtual particles. They emit real particles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [time scale for evaporation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/159943/109928) (which basically asks you to wait for the black hole temperature to be higher than the cosmic background radiation), you will find that binary black holes will have merged (due to [emission of gravitational waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave#Binaries)) a long, long time before there is any evaporation happening.