# Black Holes collapsing

Tags: black-holes, universe, big-bang

If a  black hole collapses on itself, then could the energy and matter that causes from the implosion/explosion, could a new universe/galaxy be born from that?

Answer (score 1):

A black hole is a region of space enclosed by an event horizon.  The event horizon's size is related to the mass enclosed.  It cannot collapse because that would require the mass to somehow vanish, and it won't.

There is a theoretical idea called Hawking Radiation which, in principle, allows black holes to evaporate.  But this isn't an explosion or implosion and it's a very small effect for normal black holes.

There's no reason to think a universe or galaxy can be created from a black hole.

To be clear, galaxies are not formed by either explosions or implosions (a far as we understand).

And I think you're making the common mistake of confusing the term "big bang" in cosmology with an explosion.  The big bang was not an explosion - it was an expansion of space-time.

Comment: But due to Hawking radiation also explosion can happen ,see this   http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/159937/why-would-a-black-hole-explode/159943#159943

Answer (score 1):

A black hole has already collapsed, that is how it formed if it is an astronomical black hole. It is then very stable except for growth by accreting more matter and energy, of merging with other black holes. In any of those cas s it simply grows, it does not further implode or explode.

There is only then a very slow shrinking due to emission of Hawking radiation, for astronomical objects millions or billions of years. At the end when it is tiny it bursts but there is very little left then and it goes out as gamma rays and other possible high energy particles. See black holes at Wikipedia at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole

There is some possibility that there are primordial black holes, have always been there, as opposed to astrophysical ones which collapsed from something. Also possibly miniature ones. But none of those are known or is it known how they could have formed.

There is some speculation that a wormhole could form that connects the inside of the black hole's horizon, as one gets closer to the singularity, into a white hole, where energy comes out instead of going in. Calculations have shown that those cannot be stable unless that connection from one to the other, is made up of exotic matter (such as negative mass), which we have never seen nor understand how it could be possible. Certainly not mainstream physics.