# How do we know if quantum black holes were made in the LHC?

Tags: black-holes, experimental-physics, large-hadron-collider

CERN claims that there's a possibility of formation of tiny 'quantum' black holes inside the LHC. So, if that ever happens (or have already happened), will the observers ever know about it? Can in any way a quantum black hole be visible within the LHC?

Comment: Did you read https://home.cern/resources/faqs/will-cern-generate-black-hole and the linked page within?

Comment: Probably from the distribution of the particles it throws out. But no evidence suggests that it had happened and theories are mostly against it.

Comment: More on [black holes at LHC](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/black-holes+large-hadron-collider).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Large Hadron Collider and Black Holes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/435573/)